# Identifier uint8_t is undefined - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, uint8t, type-definition

I get an error with the type definitions. 
I am working with Visual Studio 2017 and so I included stdint.h for the type definitions. But I still have the Problem that the identifier uint8_t is undefined.

What's the problem?

Comment: Works fine on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/BYunXA, you'll need to provide more info (and a [mcve])

Comment: For C++11 and later the more appropriate header would be `<cstdint>`.

Comment: When I get similar errors, it is usually because I have typed `unit` instead of `uint`. Please show the exact compiler message!

Comment: `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`?  Prefer the latter, and use the full name, `std::uint8_t`.  Note that implementations only provide fixed-width types if it's convenient for them; consider `std::uint_fast8_t` or `std::uint_least8_t` instead, according to your needs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it is defined in "stdint.h", add that on the top of your cpp-file:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: OP stated they did that

Comment: And as the answer is tagged `c++`, the answer should be `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: ok, he doesn't defined what c++ exactly he is trying...

Comment: I included <stdint.h> but it still doesn't work.. Don't know why

Comment: what type is your project?

Comment: I had a similar issue. 
I resolved that by adding **#include "stdint.h"** to the header file. Mind the order of the **#include**.